# Passing a variable into an XPath expression in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, string, xpath, casperjs

I am using CasperJS to do some browser automation. Now I have an array, which contains text that can be found on some buttons that are randomly generated on the page. I pick a random button, and assign it to a variable, and now I want to find it, and click it based on its text value.

I am having trouble building the XPath selector.

so:

```js
var pickedButton = 'my button text';
this.click(x('//*[text()="my button text"]'));
```

Can anyone point out how I can pass in a variable, instead of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just used string concatenation to build the selector:

```js
var selector = "\'//*[text()=\"" + pickedButton + "\"]\'";

this.click(x(selector));
```