# clicking dynamic text using xpath and nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I wish to click on an element with dynamic text in my app. Generally to click on an element with text I do the following:

```
.useXpath().click("//*[contains(text(), 'some text')]")
```

For my tests which have a dynamic name I try the following:

```
.useXpath().click("//*[contains(text(), "${name}")]")
```

where name is a variable which contains the name of the newly created account. However when I try to run my tests I get the following:

```
.useXpath().click("//*[contains(text(), "${name}")]")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Am I missing something? I don't see where I am missing the ). I have also tried various single/double quotes etc, but can't seem to get it working.

I have also attempted to use string concatenation as outlined here: ([Passing a variable into an XPath expression in CasperJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617282/passing-a-variable-into-an-xpath-expression-in-casperjs)), so my code looks like this:

```
 var selector = "\'//*[contains(text(), \'" + name + "\')]\'";
.useXpath().click(selector)
```

when I run the tests using this method I get the following:

```
ERROR: Unable to locate element: "'//*[contains(text(), '7ayhopt3ijhcwuo')]'" using: xpath
```

"7ayhopt3ijhcwuo" is the correct text to click on, but it does not seem to find it. Interestingly if I hard code the value like this:

```
.useXpath().click("//*[contains(text(), '7ayhopt3ijhcwuo')]")
```

nightwatch is able to click on the text without any problems.

Any help on where I am going wrong with either method would be great! I am using node v7.8.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use a back-tick character around the string to embed the variable:

```
.useXpath().click(`//*[contains(text(), "${name}")]`)
```

Or use a combination of single and double quotes:

```
.useXpath().click('//*[contains(text(), "' + name + '")]')
```

Comment: Thanks Florent B. That did the trick, both methods worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
"\'//*[contains(text(), \'" + name + "\')]\'"
```

should be

```
"//*[contains(text(), '" + name + "')]"
```

You do not need to escape the single quotes inside of a double quoted string.

Comment: Thanks Marky! Accepting Florent's answer as they were 2 minutes before you!