# Passing variables into xpath selectors in Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, xpath, nightwatch.js

EDIT: 
I believe that this is different than thread suggested as possible duplicate because I am looking for a way to use variables in page object context and this is nowhere explained there.

I am looking for a way to incorporate page objects to testing of react app. For demonstration purposes I am using: http://todomvc.com/examples/react/#/

In this case I am looking for a way to create to do task and then check it as done

I have created file (aaa.js) with page objects which look as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  url: 'http://todomvc.com/examples/react/#/',
  elements: {
        addNewItem: {
          selector: 'input[class="new-todo"]'
        },
        checkAddedItem: {
          locateStrategy: 'xpath',
          selector: '//label[contains(text(), "nightwatch")]'
        },
        crossAddedItem: {
          locateStrategy: 'xpath',
          selector: '//label[contains(text(), "nightwatch")]/parent::div/child::input'
        },
        checkIfDone: {
          selector: 'li[class="completed"]'
        }
  }
};
```

My test file (testaaa.js):

```
module.exports = {
  'Test': function (browser) {
    var aaa = browser.page.aaa();

    aaa.navigate()
      .assert.title('React • TodoMVC')
      .assert.visible('@addNewItem')
      .setValue('@addNewItem', 'nightwatch')
    browser.keys("\uE007")
    aaa.assert.visible('@checkAddedItem')
    aaa.click('@crossAddedItem')
    aaa.assert.visible('@checkIfDone')
    browser.end();
  }
};
```

Everything works but I'd like to go one step further- now I have to specify text content in selectors (nightwatch in the example)- I am looking for a way to pass a variable so I when text changes I don't have to create another selector.

Also - I am looking for a way to send Enter directly to the client without calling browser.

Thank you in advance for help and time spent on figuring it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clicking dynamic text using xpath and nightwatch.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44314715/clicking-dynamic-text-using-xpath-and-nightwatch-js)

Comment: It looks like that from Nightwatch point of view there is no API for binding XPath variables. Revert to string concatenation.

Comment: @Alejandro thanks but I do not know how to pass variable from test file (testaaa) so it can be used in the Page Object file (aaa).

Comment: _"I do not know how to pass variable from test file (testaaa) so it can be used in the Page Object file"_ that should be the question wich is now obfuscated with that XPath requeriment in body and title.

Comment: @Alejandro It is so because I didn't know about this thread- and it explains how to use variables with Xpath but not when using PO model.